# deserializing json without quoted property names with JsonSerializer.Deserialize (.net core)

Tags: json, .net-core, deserialization

I know that the specs for JSON says that propertynames (keys) should be surrounded by quotes.

But I have a lot of files that I need to read that contains data where the keys might not be quoted.

Earlier, before migration to Core, I used JavaScriptSerializer (that accepts keys without quotes ) but that doesn't exist in .net core.

Any ideas, or alternatives? I am still searching. But after 4 hours I thought that maybe you guys know this.

So, how can I read "{ apa: 23 }" and create a dictionary in .net core?

/thanks

Comment: Try using Json.net instead of the built in Json serialization system perhaps.

Comment: Lasse: Thanks! I was thinking about that. But I read that JsonSerializer was "better" and newer, so I thought I would try to find an option. It felt obvious that such thing would exist when you can have comments and trailing commas. But alas. So anyway, You convinced me. I'll use newtonsoft now instead. Weird though. Seems not so far fetched to have an option to allow this.

Comment: Well, strictly speaking what you have there is not really JSON so I was actually surprised that Json.net deserialized it out of the box without any custom options enabled at all.

Comment: Yeeahh. I got fooled. But not because of the quotes but that Json.net actually can't handle nested dictionaries. They turn out to be JObjects. I really wonder how the thinking process worked there. Why not deserialize a map to an Dictionary? So now I have sat for four ours trying to solve how to deserialize a dictionary again! But the next level down... Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please describe that situation better?

Answer (score 1):

```
Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json



string json = @"{
      'Name': 'name',
      'Description': 'des'
    }";
Test test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test>(json);
```

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate all help. And I tried that, but it seems it can't handle nested dictionaries:
"{  'Name': 'name', 'Description': { aaa: 23 }  }"
So now I try to find some other package.

Comment: Hi @eric, Could you please share your code? What Ravi Maurya did is correct. It could deserialize nested dictionary.

Comment: JsonConverter does not convert nested dictionaries to dictionaries but to JObject, according to their own documentation.